# Upgrade 2.6 to 2.7 State Processor

Tags: api-platform.com

I want to change a DataTransformer to State processor.
Here my entry points configuration:

```
    new Post(
        uriTemplate: '/orders/request',
        status: 301,
        controller: PostOrderRequest::class,
        security: 'is_granted("ROLE_USER")',
        securityPostDenormalize: 'is_granted("create", object)',
        input: OrderRequestInputDto::class,
        read: false,
        processor: OrderRequestInputProcessor::class
    )
```

With the DataTransformer all works fine but with the processor not.
If I dump the subject in my Voter I see the InputDto instead of the Entity processed by the State processor and if I dump the $data invoke by the custom controller I see the InputDto instead of Entity.

Can you explain me what can I do?

Thanks so much.